# Disable Lottie animation for mobile in Elementor

Tags: elementor, lottie

i've created some icon animation in After effects and i've imported them as lottie files in Wordpress.

I'm using Elementor page builder, is there a way to disable those lottie animations only on mobile ?

Thanks